# GStreamer. Play raw h264 from udp

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, gstreamer-1.0

I'm getting raw h264 stream from some camera and i need to play that using the gst.
At first i tried to save the stream to the file (using my own application which just writes stream to a file) and pay using filesrc:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="file path" ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink
```

That works OK. Then i tried to play from the udpsrc:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=1234 ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink
```

And got next error (after start stream from camera):

> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format
> Additional debug info:
> gstcapsfilter.c(453): gst_capsfilter_prepare_buf (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0:
> Output caps are unfixed: video/x-h264, width=(int)[ 1, 8192 ], height=(int)[ 1, 8192 ], framerate=(fraction){ 30/1, [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ] }
> Execution ended after 0:00:04.234834646

I'm new in GST.
Please, help me)))

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink
```

For real-time stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```